# Windows Batch or VB Script to add a extension than add a line to the end of the .csv file

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

Each day there are 4 files downloaded to a mapped drive, without a extension. I have searched for a script what I want but I could not find it. I have found out a cmd script but only adding a csv as extension. But I want all scripts in 1 file. Maybe someone can help me.

Add extension to this files:

```
daily1.20121129
daily2.20121129
equity.20121129
future4.20121129
```

(.20121129' this is the date that's downloaded, each day this is changed.)

Script has to add text in to 2 files on the end of each file: 'daily1.date.csv' and 'daily2.date.csv' the date is changed each day I think script has to open it if contained with daily1 and daily2.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  To accomplish this, I would use FileScriptingObject to open each file, and then write out the edited lines.  After you have the files edited, call a batch file to concatenate the files into one file with the extension you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite certain what you want to achieve. Do you want all downloaded files to go into one file with the extension `.csv`? That could be achieved like this (assuming no other files are in the directory):

```
>output.csv type *
```

Or do you want to add the extension `.csv` to each downloaded file? That coule be achieved like this (again, assuming no other files are in the directory):

```
for %%f in (*) do ren "%%~f" "%%~f.csv"
```

Or do you want to merge only specific files? If so, which source files should go into which destination file?

Or do you need to distinguish the files with the current date from other files in the same directory? For that you'd need to build a date string, which depends on the date format defined in your computers regional settings. Assuming a format `MM/DD/YYYY` you could build a date string `YYYYMMDD` like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%i in ("%DATE%") do set d=%%k%%i%%j

REM do stuff

endlocal
```

**Edit:**

To append text to files before or after renaming them, you could incorporate those actions into the loop:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (*) do (
  set filename=%%~f
  if "!filename:~0,5!" == "daily" echo something >> "!filename!"
  ren "!filename!" "!filename!.csv"
)

endlocal
```

Of course you'll need two statements if you want to append different somethings to the two files.

```
if "!filename:~0,6!" == "daily1" echo something >> "!filename!"
if "!filename:~0,6!" == "daily2" echo something else >> "!filename!"
```

Comment: No/Yes. the files are download from another program to the folder. The script has to add a extension to all files. This is good for %%f in (*) do ren "%%~f" "%%~f.csv"

Comment: the second is that a specifiek tekst have to be added on the bottom. This is only in 2 files. That's daily1 and daily2

Comment: What i want to achieve is, to make a batch thats runs from task scheduler. Each day the script has to add .csv on the files. Than 2 files has to be opened and added on the end of the file added a tekst.

Comment: I have found this : echo Test >> C:\TEST\file.name.csv But this is not good, i need to open 2 files. i hope someone can help me i will search.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rename all the files in the folder to a csv extension then you can use

```
ren C:\folder\files\* *.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used some other forums, but this is what i wanted. Sorry that i was not correct what i wanted. Maybe in the future it will help other people.

```
ren C:\blp\bbdl\_csv\* *?.csv
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 6
for %%j in (C:\blp\bbdl\_csv\dailycurrency1.out.????????.csv) do @echo.TEST EUR>> %%j
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 6
for %%j in (C:\blp\bbdl\_csv\dailycurrency2.out.????????.csv) do @echo.TEST >> %%j
PING 127.0.0.1 -n 6
powershell -command "& 'C:\NewScript\copy_script_PS.ps1' "
```